# ReactNavice Onesignal Integration Issiue

Tags: react-native, onesignal

```
public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication 
{

    private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost=new ReactNativeHost(this){

    @Override public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport(){return BuildConfig.DEBUG;}

    @Override protected List<ReactPackage>getPackages(){
    return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
          new ReactNativeOneSignalPackage(),
          new MapsPackage(),
          new VectorIconsPackage());
    }

   @Override protected String getJSMainModuleName(){return"index";}
   };

   @Override
       public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
       return mReactNativeHost;
   }

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
      super.onCreate();
      SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
   }

   //This part is giving error:
   @Override
   public List<ReactPackage> createAdditionalReactPackages() {
       return getPackages();
   }

}
```

Hi there i have a problem with integration onesignal push notification into myapp.
As you see i added necessary codes as documanted. But onesignal is not working and if i add createAdditionalReactPackages it gives error and not building. If i remove that part project building succesfully but onIds not working.
 What is wrong i dont understand please help me

Thanks in advance.